# How to answer the questions asked by a bash script that has been called from a python script without human intervention

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have a bash script that I invoke from my python script through `subprocess.call`; however, that bash script when run alone asks for an user input. I want to provide this input through my python script itself rather than having an user answering it manually.

So I basically want to invoke a bash script from python script and then provide an input through the code itself to one of the questions that gets generated on the execution of that bash script.

Here is what I have currently:

```
subprocess.call("/bin/bash "+sample.sh ,shell=True)
```

Executing this, `sample.sh` asks for user prompt:

> what is your name?

and I want to pass that name from the python code itself.

I would be grateful for any pointers. Thank you.

Comment: Not the answer you hoped to get, but why doesn't you turn the bash script to a python function? Therefore you could easily handle arguments... I want to add, that subprocess supports arguments -> [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) , but (imo) not flexible input while running.

Comment: Use command line arguments for passing the name instead of prompting to enter the name in your bash script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) seems to do exactly what you need. As an example :

```
child = pexpect.spawn('scp foo myname@host.example.com:.')
child.expect ('Password:')
child.sendline (mypassword)
```

Here's the [github repo](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect). You can install `pexpect` with :

```
pip install pexpect
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve that issue using `bash` and `expect`. Here is an example to do a remote ssh connection and executing `ls -l /`:

```
export IP=<ip>
export PAS=<passwd>
expect -c 'spawn ssh root@$env(IP) "ls -l  /"; expect "password:"; send "$env(PAS)\n"; interact;'
```

When expect receives string "password:" it sends the content of variable PASS (the password), so you can do the ssh connection and execute the remote command without writing the password explicitly.